# move recently created files matching a pattern from one folder to a different one

Tags: bash, shell, files, scripting, regular-expression

I am looking for a bash script example which does the following:

I have files being written under `/tmp` folder

I do at the `xterm` prompt, `ls -ltr` which gives me a list of recent files such as:

```
abc_mytest.log
abc_runTimeFailure.scripted.log
myManager.log
```

I want to move (`mv`) the most recent ones that were written today to a new folder which is under /home/project/.

I only want to move the ones that were created in `/tmp` in today's date only to `/home/project/`

Any example that the community can share will save me time before I re-invent the wheel.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: What are the `%` symbols on the front of your filenames?

Comment: These are just my Linux Xterm prompt.

Comment: LinuxMachine-username% abc_mytest.log

LinuxMachine-username% abc_runTimeFailure.scripted.log

LinuxMachine-username% myManager.log

Comment: (1) Please don’t use symbols misleadingly.  Your “>>” is confusing, and the shell prompt should appear at the left ***of the* `ls` *command**,* not at the beginning of every line of output.  (2) Look at ``find``. … … … … P.S.  Why do you believe that your question has anything to do with regular expressions? … … … … … … … … P.P.S. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Your prompt does not appear at the beginning of each line of output. Only when you're being prompted (hence its name). But better is not to include the prompt at all, so that copy'n'paste can work

Comment: Not all of the files in `/tmp` owned by you should be moved out. Some of them may be temporary files owned by other processes that happen to belong to you. What you're asking could even cause your GUI session to crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `man find mv` and do something like:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mtime 0 \
  -exec mv -t /home/project/ {} +
```

**UNTESTED!** You must test with `echo mv` instead of the potentially dangerous  `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age
mv /tmp/*(.e[age today]) /home/project/
```

(add the `D` glob qualifier if you also want to move hidden files last modified today).

Note that `/tmp` is a temporary directory used by every user of the system including system user. It sounds like a bad idea to try moving files that may potentially not be your own (the system won't let you do it though unless you're doing it as `root`).

To only consider files that you own, use the `U` glob qualifier. You could also move only files whose name matches a given pattern like the ones that end in `.log`:

```
mv /tmp/*.log(.Ue[age today]) /home/project/
```